# Strange behavior on function argument in C

Tags: c, arm

I have a problem with a program running in an ARM4 MCU.
Debugging the code I found this situation: The function changeBackColor calls drawn with the argument this (this=0x1fffc4d3 first image), inside the function draw, immediately after call, the value of this is different (this=0xffc4d3 second image).

[changeBackColor function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XArDy.png)

[drawn function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAZgh.png)

Adittional information:
I have no leak in heap memory;
I can not reproduce the problem in unit tests;
The problem only appears when running the entire system.

Comment: `this` is not used by `changeBackColor` after calling `drawn` so it got optimized away.

Comment: When posting questions on StackOverflow, please (a) never post *images* of text, and (b) never refer to remote content. Include the code you are asking about *in the question*, as text, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to use the same memory for different variables if their uses don't overlap. This is a very useful optimization on microcontrollers with little memory.

Comment: @larsks It's not clear how they can achieve that when a critical part of the question is the display from a GUI debugger. It's hard to post that as text.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure that the "display from a GUI debugger" added anything useful here, and hiding the code behind a remote image means that this question will become meaningless when those links expire. It also makes the question inaccessible to anyone accessing the site using a screen reader or other assistive device.

Comment: @larsks I agree that the code should be text. But his question is why the debugger is showing the wrong value for a variable, so he needs to show the debugger output.

Comment: The problem appears to be a bug outside the posted code/debugger output anyway, so this problem isn't reproducible.

Comment: Another thing of note: don't be so eager jump to conclusions about strange values shown for watched parameters in the C source, particularly when just entering a function. Sometimes it takes multiple asm instructions to set a value or execute calling convention stacking of parameters. And then you'll observe the correct values if you single step on the assembler level instead. All half-decent debuggers have this option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all help.
About suggests: For this situation, it is not possible to post the entire code; The optimization was disabled.

The solution:

This is the code for the drawn function:

```
static void drawn(TextField * this)
{
  size_t cps = strlen(this->text);
  size_t cls = this->length - cps;
  uint8_t nx = this->px + (this->font->width + 1) * cps;
  char str[] = SPACES;
  str[cls] = '\0';

  if (this->trimSpaces)
  { \\...
  }
  \\...
}
```

this->length is a property that holds the length of the textField. I do not know the reason, but I got a miss behavior on strlen(this->text). Its returning a number greater than length, than cls became to high, and the instruction:  "str[cls] = '\0';" is overwriting the memory in the same position of the first byte of the variable this.

Comment: The debugger shoulds `cls` as `0xFFFFFFFF`, which either means that it was explicitly assigned the value -1. You seem to have bugs but not necessarily located inside the function you have posted.